# What kind of routes can be propagated to VPC route tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, bgp

in AWS, What kind of routes can be propagated to VPC route tables ?

I know:

- site-to-site VPN routes via Virtual Private Gateway

anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure VPC route tables for route propagation such that VPN and Direct Connect/Direct Connect Gateway prefixes from the Virtual Private Gateway (VGW) populate the routing table. If you have a background in networking, you can think of the VGW as a BGP-speaking router.

For VPCs connected using Transit Gateway (TGW), there is no route propagation for the spoke VPC routing tables. You must add static routes in the VPC route tables with the Transit Gateway as the target. Note that there is a concept of route propagation for TGWs that applies to TGW routing tables.